# What is the English word for a graduation award?

Tags: word-request

I was wondering if there was a specific word for this particular type of plaque/award? It's given to college graduates, to commemorate and represent their degree. 
I think it's mostly just called award/plaque, but I was looking for a better word to describe this particular object. Thank you!

[image: graduation]

Comment: What does the site www.Bode4.com call it?

Answer (score 9):

Interesting, I have never seen something like that here in the U.S. Usually we just get a diploma for graduating. You might call this a *trophy*- that’s a 3D award for something that stands up on its own- usually in the shape of a cup but not always. I think a *plaque* would be more flat and something you’d hang on the wall.

Comment: Here in the UK you get a certificate and a transcript, on hard-to-forge paper that costs a bunch to replace if you lose it. That's about it.

Comment: @SamBC If you obtain a PhD from the University of Cambridge, your certificate is laser printed in black and white on 80gsm paper.  (A parking permit for the Engineering Labs on the other hand, has holograms and other anti-forgery devices.)

Comment: I can see why they'd worry less about forged PhDs thank bachelor's degrees

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with *statue*. The site is full of *statues of appreciation* (as they describe them).

Comment: Or even statuette, for a small one!

Comment: I always think of a statue(tte) as being in the shape of a person - like an Academy Award. Maybe that’s not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "crest" in our country. Perhaps the meaning in this context is

> **Crest**- A distinctive device representing a family or corporate body, borne above the shield of a coat of arms (originally as worn on a helmet) or separately reproduced, for example on writing paper.

Comment: The definition you have quoted fits the meaning as I understand it (British English), but I would not describe the OPs photo as a crest.